# CSS Анимация, плавное изменение background-image

Tags: html, css

Всем доброго вечера, есть анимация:

```
@keyframes headerLane {
    0% {
        background-image: url(../images/header_1.jpg);
    }

    50% {
        background-image: url(../images/header_2.jpg);
    }

    100% {
        background-image: url(../images/header_3.jpg);
    }
}
```

Вот я применяю её к блоку:

```
animation: headerLane 7s linear infinite alternate;
background-position: 0px 70% !important;
background-size: cover;
```

Вопрос заключается в следующем: почему изображения меняются плавно, как будто к ним добавлено свойство transition? Разве оно не должно просто в течении 7 секунд переключится 3 раза?

Если в этом и заключается суть анимации, не только в повторении движения а ещё и исполнения этого плавно то у меня возникает вопрос, как сделать резкую смену картинок без всяческих эффектов?

Comment: steps() наверно нужен

Answer (score 3):

Могу предложить вот такой вариант, работает скачками как вы просили:
(для 4-ех картинок будет 0%,25%,50,75%,100% последняя и предпоследняя должны повторятся, так как 100% это конец анимации)

```
@keyframes headerLane {
    0% {
        background-image: url(../images/header_1.jpg);
    }
    33% {
        background-image: url(../images/header_2.jpg);
    }
    66% {
        background-image: url(../images/header_3.jpg);
    }
    100% {
        background-image: url(../images/header_3.jpg);
    }
}
```

Код анимации (можете перепить в одну строку):

```
animation-name: headerLane;
animation-duration: 21s;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);
```

PS: длительность нужно умножать на количество элементов которое вы хотите слайдить

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное!!! У меня это свойство есть, просто я думал - 2 картинки - значит степс 2... Оказалось нужно ставить степс 1. А end - значение по умолчанию... animation: an 1s steps(1) infinite ;
И все круто работает)))

Answer (score 0):

https://html5book.ru/css3-animation/
Вот хорошая статья про анимации, обратите внимание на 8 пункт, если я все правильно понял, вы записали кратко свойство animation-duration, которое описывается в 3 пункте, поэтому у вас и происходит плавная анимация.

Answer (score 0):

Именно за то что вам необходимо отвечает свойство:     `animation-timing-function: steps(1, end);` и так как оно отсутствует в вашем коде результат не получается должным.